# calling array in main class

Tags: android

I have two classes and one class contain string array and its constructor how to call it in main with its object?

Comment: @Sam: Maybe they don't natively speak english?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code?  I can't really understand what you're asking

Comment: Try re-wording your question. In its current form, it is not clear what you asking.

Comment: you have a `main()` in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Reading this tutorial should answer your question:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html

It will show you how to Create an Activity. From this Activity, which is launched when you open you application, you will be able to create instances of the class you have created.